# First chance System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException "This element is not currently associated with any context"

Tags: wcf, first-chance-exception

Does anyone know what this particular exception mean and how to fix it?

Note, that I am not asking for help on suppressing it in the Exceptions dialog. I want to understand the root cause of it and how to fix the cause itself, if at all possible.

Thanks.

P.S.

The line that causes FCE is:

```
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfPortal)))
```

Exception details:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException occurred
  Message="This element is not currently associated with any context"
  Source="System.Configuration"
  BareMessage="This element is not currently associated with any context"
  Line=0
  StackTrace:
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.get_EvaluationContext()
  InnerException:
```

The call stack is:

```
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.EvaluationContext.get() + 0x64 bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelExtensionElement.System.ServiceModel.Configuration.IConfigurationContextProviderInternal.GetEvaluationContext() + 0x1f bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.GetEvaluationContext(System.ServiceModel.Configuration.IConfigurationContextProviderInternal provider = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceDebugElement}) + 0x41 bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelExtensionElement.GetConfigurationElementName() + 0x72 bytes   
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelExtensionElement.ConfigurationElementName.get() + 0x3a bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelExtensionCollectionElement<System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorExtensionElement>.Add(System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorExtensionElement element = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceDebugElement}) + 0x2a6 bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceBehaviorElement.Add(System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorExtensionElement element = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceDebugElement}) + 0x16b bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelExtensionCollectionElement<System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorExtensionElement>.DeserializeElementCore(System.Xml.XmlReader reader = {Element, Name="serviceDebug"}) + 0x1eb bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelExtensionCollectionElement<System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorExtensionElement>.DeserializeElement(System.Xml.XmlReader reader = {Element, Name="serviceDebug"}, bool serializeCollectionKey = false) + 0x2f bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceBehaviorElement.DeserializeElement(System.Xml.XmlReader reader = {Element, Name="serviceDebug"}, bool serializeCollectionKey = false) + 0x2b bytes 
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection.OnDeserializeUnrecognizedElement(string elementName = "behavior", System.Xml.XmlReader reader = {Element, Name="serviceDebug"}) + 0xc0 bytes   
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.DeserializeElement(System.Xml.XmlReader reader = {Element, Name="serviceDebug"}, bool serializeCollectionKey = false) + 0xf48 bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceBehaviorElementCollection.DeserializeElement(System.Xml.XmlReader reader = {Element, Name="serviceDebug"}, bool serializeCollectionKey = false) + 0x2a bytes   
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.DeserializeElement(System.Xml.XmlReader reader = {Element, Name="serviceDebug"}, bool serializeCollectionKey = false) + 0xe6c bytes  
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection.DeserializeSection(System.Xml.XmlReader reader = {Element, Name="serviceDebug"}) + 0x8a bytes    
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.CreateSectionImpl(System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord = ConfigPath = "MACHINE/EXE", System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "system.serviceModel/behaviors", System.Configuration.SectionRecord sectionRecord = SectionRecord "system.serviceModel/behaviors", object parentConfig = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorsSection}, System.Configuration.ConfigXmlReader reader = {Element, Name="serviceDebug"}) + 0xf6 bytes    
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.CreateSectionWithRestrictedPermissions(System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord = ConfigPath = "MACHINE/EXE", System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "system.serviceModel/behaviors", System.Configuration.SectionRecord sectionRecord = SectionRecord "system.serviceModel/behaviors", object parentConfig = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorsSection}, System.Configuration.ConfigXmlReader reader = {Element, Name="serviceDebug"}) + 0x98 bytes   
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.CreateSection(bool inputIsTrusted = false, System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord = ConfigPath = "MACHINE/EXE", System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "system.serviceModel/behaviors", System.Configuration.SectionRecord sectionRecord = SectionRecord "system.serviceModel/behaviors", object parentConfig = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorsSection}, System.Configuration.ConfigXmlReader reader = {Element, Name="serviceDebug"}) + 0x5e bytes   
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSection(bool inputIsTrusted = false, System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "system.serviceModel/behaviors", System.Configuration.SectionRecord sectionRecord = SectionRecord "system.serviceModel/behaviors", object parentConfig = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorsSection}, System.Configuration.ConfigXmlReader reader = {Element, Name="serviceDebug"}) + 0x7a bytes  
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.CallCreateSection(bool inputIsTrusted = false, System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "system.serviceModel/behaviors", System.Configuration.SectionRecord sectionRecord = SectionRecord "system.serviceModel/behaviors", object parentConfig = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorsSection}, System.Configuration.ConfigXmlReader reader = {Element, Name="serviceDebug"}, string filename = "C:\\Dev\\windows\\bin\\Debug\\Server.Host.exe.Config", int line = 89) + 0x74 bytes    
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(string[] keys = {string[2]}, System.Configuration.SectionInput input = SectionInput "system.serviceModel/behaviors", bool isTrusted = false, System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "system.serviceModel/behaviors", System.Configuration.SectionRecord sectionRecord = SectionRecord "system.serviceModel/behaviors", object parentResult = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorsSection}) + 0x115 bytes    
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "system.serviceModel/behaviors", System.Configuration.SectionRecord sectionRecord = SectionRecord "system.serviceModel/behaviors", object parentResult = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorsSection}, bool getLkg = false, bool getRuntimeObject = true, out object result = null, out object resultRuntimeObject = null) + 0x626 bytes    
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(string configKey = "system.serviceModel/behaviors", bool getLkg = false, bool checkPermission = true, bool getRuntimeObject = true, bool requestIsHere = true, out object result = null, out object resultRuntimeObject = null) + 0x670 bytes 
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(string configKey = "system.serviceModel/behaviors", bool getLkg = false, bool checkPermission = true) + 0x44 bytes 
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(string configKey = "system.serviceModel/behaviors") + 0x2a bytes   
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ContextInformation.GetSection(string sectionName = "system.serviceModel/behaviors") + 0x2a bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.UnsafeGetSectionFromContext(System.Configuration.ContextInformation evalContext = {System.Configuration.ContextInformation}, string sectionPath = "system.serviceModel/behaviors") + 0x3a bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.UnsafeGetAssociatedSection(System.Configuration.ContextInformation evalContext = {System.Configuration.ContextInformation}, string sectionPath = "system.serviceModel/behaviors") + 0x3b bytes   
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorsSection.ValidateServiceBehaviorReference(string behaviorConfiguration = "serviceBehavior", System.Configuration.ContextInformation evaluationContext = {System.Configuration.ContextInformation}, System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement configurationElement = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceElement}) + 0x66 bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServicesSection.ValidateSection() + 0xe7 bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServicesSection.PostDeserialize() + 0x1e bytes    
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.DeserializeElement(System.Xml.XmlReader reader = {EndElement, Name="services"}, bool serializeCollectionKey = false) + 0x1fef bytes  
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection.DeserializeSection(System.Xml.XmlReader reader = {EndElement, Name="services"}) + 0x8a bytes 
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.CreateSectionImpl(System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord = ConfigPath = "MACHINE/EXE", System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "system.serviceModel/services", System.Configuration.SectionRecord sectionRecord = SectionRecord "system.serviceModel/services", object parentConfig = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServicesSection}, System.Configuration.ConfigXmlReader reader = {EndElement, Name="services"}) + 0xf6 bytes    
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.CreateSectionWithRestrictedPermissions(System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord = ConfigPath = "MACHINE/EXE", System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "system.serviceModel/services", System.Configuration.SectionRecord sectionRecord = SectionRecord "system.serviceModel/services", object parentConfig = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServicesSection}, System.Configuration.ConfigXmlReader reader = {EndElement, Name="services"}) + 0x98 bytes   
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.CreateSection(bool inputIsTrusted = false, System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord = ConfigPath = "MACHINE/EXE", System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "system.serviceModel/services", System.Configuration.SectionRecord sectionRecord = SectionRecord "system.serviceModel/services", object parentConfig = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServicesSection}, System.Configuration.ConfigXmlReader reader = {EndElement, Name="services"}) + 0x5e bytes   
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSection(bool inputIsTrusted = false, System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "system.serviceModel/services", System.Configuration.SectionRecord sectionRecord = SectionRecord "system.serviceModel/services", object parentConfig = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServicesSection}, System.Configuration.ConfigXmlReader reader = {EndElement, Name="services"}) + 0x7a bytes  
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.CallCreateSection(bool inputIsTrusted = false, System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "system.serviceModel/services", System.Configuration.SectionRecord sectionRecord = SectionRecord "system.serviceModel/services", object parentConfig = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServicesSection}, System.Configuration.ConfigXmlReader reader = {EndElement, Name="services"}, string filename = "C:\\Dev\\windows\\bin\\Debug\\Server.Host.exe.Config", int line = 78) + 0x74 bytes    
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(string[] keys = {string[2]}, System.Configuration.SectionInput input = SectionInput "system.serviceModel/services", bool isTrusted = false, System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "system.serviceModel/services", System.Configuration.SectionRecord sectionRecord = SectionRecord "system.serviceModel/services", object parentResult = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServicesSection}) + 0x115 bytes    
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "system.serviceModel/services", System.Configuration.SectionRecord sectionRecord = SectionRecord "system.serviceModel/services", object parentResult = {System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServicesSection}, bool getLkg = false, bool getRuntimeObject = true, out object result = null, out object resultRuntimeObject = null) + 0x626 bytes   
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(string configKey = "system.serviceModel/services", bool getLkg = false, bool checkPermission = false, bool getRuntimeObject = true, bool requestIsHere = false, out object result = null, out object resultRuntimeObject = null) + 0x670 bytes    
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(string configKey = "system.serviceModel/services", bool getLkg = false, bool checkPermission = false, bool getRuntimeObject = true, bool requestIsHere = false, out object result = null, out object resultRuntimeObject = null) + 0x63d bytes    
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(string configKey = "system.serviceModel/services", bool getLkg = false, bool checkPermission = true, bool getRuntimeObject = true, bool requestIsHere = true, out object result = null, out object resultRuntimeObject = null) + 0x63d bytes  
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(string configKey = "system.serviceModel/services", bool getLkg = false, bool checkPermission = true) + 0x44 bytes  
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(string configKey = "system.serviceModel/services") + 0x2a bytes    
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(string sectionName = "system.serviceModel/services") + 0x7e bytes    
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(string sectionName = "system.serviceModel/services") + 0x48 bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.UnsafeGetSectionFromConfigurationManager(string sectionPath = "system.serviceModel/services") + 0x31 bytes   
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.UnsafeGetAssociatedSection(System.Configuration.ContextInformation evalContext = null, string sectionPath = "system.serviceModel/services") + 0xac bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.UnsafeGetSection(string sectionPath = "system.serviceModel/services") + 0x22 bytes   
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServicesSection.UnsafeGetSection() + 0x26 bytes   
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupService(string serviceConfigurationName = "Csla.Server.Hosts.WcfPortal") + 0x39 bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader configLoader = {System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader}, System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription description = ServiceType={Csla.Server.Hosts.WcfPortal}, string configurationName = "Csla.Server.Hosts.WcfPortal") + 0x2d bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ApplyConfiguration() + 0xfa bytes   
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(System.ServiceModel.UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses = {System.ServiceModel.UriSchemeKeyedCollection}) + 0xf8 bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(System.Type serviceType = {Name = "WcfPortal" FullName = "Csla.Server.Hosts.WcfPortal"}, System.ServiceModel.UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses = {System.ServiceModel.UriSchemeKeyedCollection}) + 0x83 bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.ServiceHost(System.Type serviceType = {Name = "WcfPortal" FullName = "Csla.Server.Hosts.WcfPortal"}, System.Uri[] baseAddresses = {System.Uri[0]}) + 0x16a bytes    
Server.Host.exe!Server.Host.Program.Main(string[] args = {string[0]}) Line 37 + 0x38 bytes  C#
```

**EDIT**

The issue does not produce itself after upgrading to .NET 4 and VS2010. I guess MS fixed it.

Comment: Please provide details. Are you seeing this in the debugger? Also, please post the full exception.

Answer (score 5):

I've had a similar issue in the past when dealing with WCF. In this case, it was basically MS code swallowing an exception but it was still caught as a FCE when in debug mode. See [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/2620084b-a77b-4c77-b9ce-725fbea1df55/) for more info.

If your issue is in WCF, an appropriate workaround is to suppress the FCE dialog since you can't do much about it. If it's not WCF related, I suspect that it might be in another base class library or third party dll you are using. Either way, not much you can do about it. In my experience, I've never seen this exception lead to anything meaningful.

If you believe it might be of some value, you might want to post a bit more contextual information about where the exception originated from so that folks can chime in and be of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the following solution worked:

1. I found configuration (settings) file, my program used (in the exception details).
2. I stopped debugging.
3. I deleted configuration file from the location, I found.
4. I recompliled my app..

Hope will work in your case too :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just wasted an hour or so, after hitting exactly the same problem.

I have a WPF app, which was successfully calling a Web Service and getting some data.

But... this morning, I went into the Exceptions dialog in VS2008, and asked it to throw an exception on "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".

From then on, my app would crash as soon as it hit the line to initialise my webservice variable:

**MikesWebServiceSoapClient client = new MikesWebServiceSoapClient ();**

*A first chance exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll
Additional information: This element is not currently associated with any context*

I did read the comments in this StackOverflow thread, but was confused.  In the Exceptions dialog, I could disable the "System.Configuration" exceptions from being thrown... but this exception WOULD still occur.  And I didn't have any other exceptions relating to System.Configuration that I could untick.

I even tried leaving "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" ticked, but unticking every one of it's children.  But my app would still crash with an exception...

Eventually, I realised that in the Exceptions dialog, I needed to **add** a new Exception type called "*System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException*", click on OK, then UNTICK this new Exception type.

Now, my app would run, the exception would silently occur, but the app would keep running.

I do like WPF, but it's ridiculous how much time I waste chasing down silly problems like this that've been around for years.

I wouldn't mind, but this was a WebService variable created by VS2008... and it's always worked fine.  Until you ask WPF to pay attention to exceptions, that is...

Answer (score -1):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/e2d07245-b305-4d12-82e5-6074175271d6

> Data Developer Center >  Data Platform Development Forums   >  WCF
>   Data Services (formerly known as ADO.NET Data Services)   >  First
>   chance System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException “This element
>   is not currently associated with any context”

Silverlight web services.

Re the above, after much experimentation, I found what works to solve this bug --you change everything from Debug to Release.  This means changing all attributes such as  (from ="true") in the web.config file, as well as setting the Configuration Manager of Visual Studio from Debug to Release.

When you do this, the bug disappears.  And my original workaround is wrong--no need to change from a Dataset to a class, as I suggested.  Once you make the change to Release the bug disappears.