# Convert a SAML 2.0 xml element token to a .NET System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken

Tags: c#, wcf, single-sign-on, wif

I have a SAML 2.0 bearer token that I acquired using a third party library from our SSO server. Now I'm trying to use this token to authenticate against a soution. The problem I'm having is my token is of type `XmlElement` and I need to convert it to `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken` type because `ChannelFactory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken` expects a `SecurityToken` type. Any ideas?

BTW I have seen this post [How to convert SAML XML token string to either SecurityToken or ClaimsPrincipal instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562162/how-to-convert-saml-xml-token-string-to-either-securitytoken-or-claimsprincipal) but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be exact - for that method you need to convert it to a GenericXmlSecurityToken - just use the ctor (you can ignore aka null most other parameters).